# ngFor over object populated from promise in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, jszip

I'm parsing a zip file with images that I want to reference with a blobURL in a `filesFromZip` object, and iterate over it with ngFor to show the images on the page.

It looks like this

```
filesFromZip = {};
let zip = new JSZip();

zip.loadAsync(zipfileFromInput)
  .then(function (zip) {
    for (let file in zip.files) {

    let fileInZip = zip.files[file];

    zip.file(fileInZip.name)
      .async("arraybuffer")
      .then(function (content) {
        let buffer = new Uint8Array(content);
        let blob = new Blob([buffer.buffer]);

        // here is where I want to push this object into the filesFromZip object somehow....
        return {
          fileName: fileInZip.name,
          blobURL: URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        };
    });
   }
  });
```

in the template:

```
<md-card *ngFor="let file of filesFromZip">
  <h3 md-line>{{file.fileName}}</h3>
  <img src="{{file.blobURL}}">
</md-card>
```

How can I get the data from the promise to `filesFromZip`?

I've tried to just push it into `filesFromZip` but that gives me this error:

> error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'async' of null

I'm really struggling with asynchronicity and Angular 2. Somebody who can send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot iterate over a plain object with the `*ngFor` directive, so `filesFromZip` should be an array.

```
this.filesFromZip = [];
zip.loadAsync(zipfileFromInput)
  .then((zip)=> {
    for (let file in zip.files) {
      let fileInZip = zip.files[file];
      zip.file(fileInZip.name)
        .async("arraybuffer")
        .then((content)=> {
          let buffer = new Uint8Array(content);
          let blob = new Blob([buffer.buffer]);
          // here is where I want to push this object into the filesFromZip object somehow....
          this.filesFromZip.push({
            fileName: fileInZip.name,
            blobURL: URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          });
      });
   }
  });
```

or you can use Promise.all() that will create a promise from an iterable of Promise and then use the async pipe :

**javascript :**

```
this.filesFromZip = Promise.all(
  zip.loadAsync(zipfileFromInput)
    .then((zip)=> {
      let out=[];
      for (let file in zip.files) {
        let fileInZip = zip.files[file];
        out.push(zip.file(fileInZip.name)
          .async("arraybuffer")
          .then((content)=> {
            let buffer = new Uint8Array(content);
            let blob = new Blob([buffer.buffer]);
            // here is where I want to push this object into the filesFromZip object somehow....
            this.filesFromZip.push({
              fileName: fileInZip.name,
              blobURL: URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            });
        }));
    }
    return out;
    });
)
```

**template :**

```
<md-card *ngFor="let file of filesFromZip|async">
  <h3 md-line>{{file.fileName}}</h3>
  <img src="{{file.blobURL}}">
</md-card>
```

However, your main problem here seems to be that `zip.file(fileInZip.name)` is returning `null`

Comment: To use the async pipe shouldn't filesFromZip return a promise, and not as I do now trying to return an object?

Comment: Just a new empty object that I tried to push the result from the promise into

Comment: you mean this result :
`return { fileName: fileInZip.name, blobURL: URL.createObjectURL(blob) };` ? Because as this is returned by a promise, it will become a promise...

Comment: Yes, I tried to push that object for every file into filesFromZip instead of returning it, but it gave an error. But now the returned object only lives in the promise and I don't know how to get it to filesFromZip

Comment: Where does that `filesFromZip` variable come from !!!??? Please edit your question with all the necessary informations...

Comment: It feels like we're getting closer to the solution. But i get an error: `Error:(36, 39) TS2345:Argument of type 'Promise<JSZip>' is not assignable to parameter of type '({} | PromiseLike<{}>)[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Promise<JSZip>'`. I can't put zip.LoadAsync... in Promise.all(...